# Submit Angular Material Selection List values as PostBody

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular5

I have a list of selection based on mat-selection-list, like this setup below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
I want to submit my selections as PostBody, my backend endpoint expects postbody in the following structure:

```
{
    "taskTypeAreas": [
        {
            "name": "Area1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Area2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Area3"
        }
    ]
}
```

on my component.ts I call the service like below:

```
  submitNames() {

        let Names  =  this.selectedOptions; // here i want to submit user selectons
        this.myservice.nameService(Names).subscribe(res => {
          console.log('Results' + JSON.stringify(res));
          }
        );
      }


  onNgModelChange(event){
    console.log('on ng model change', event);
    }
```

in Template:

```
  <mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of taskTypeAreas" [value]="tta.name">
        {{tta.name}}
      </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
  <div>
      <p Selection: {{ selectedOptions }}</p> 
      <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" (click)="submitNames()">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

When clicking submit, the response returned is HTTP status code 400 (Bad request)and request payload looks like this: ["Area1"], how to modify PostBody to be understood by the server according to the pattern above?

Comment: This looks fairly simple, but I may be overlooking something. Try `[value]="tta"` on mat-list-option.

Comment: @G.Tranter why to change [value]="tta.name" to [value]="tta", i have no probelm in selection values, i need to restructure "let Names  =  this.selectedOptions;"
it returns an array with name value like this: [Area1], it should be in a form that the server accepts.

Comment: `[value]` has nothing to do with selections that you see in the list - it is what gets stored in the model or form control. Your request data is `["Area1"]` but it should be `[{"name": "Area1"}]`. Similarly, `tta.name` is `"Area1"` and `tta` is `{"name": "Area1"}`.

Comment: Simply create the { "taskTypeAreas": <payload> } object when you are submitting.

Comment: @G.Tranter That solved it :) thank you

Comment: @G.Tranter I would like to extend this to a service to check if a name is selected by the user previously to display it as selected, now I can post my selections successfully,  how to add a logic like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-material-jyycr7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
but instead of hardcoding selection based on boolean ,i would like to introduce a service that checks selections from another service which has all these taskTypeAreas and other preferences.